# isActionUp in andEngine does not work

Tags: android, physics, andengine

I have a very simple andEngine project. I have overridden the `onSceneTouchEvent` as follows:

```
@Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) 
    {
        if(this.mPhysicsWorld != null) 
        {
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp())
            {
                this.addFace(200, 20);
            }

            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown())
            {
                this.addFace(20, 20);
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

When I run it and touch the screen, `addFace(20,20)`, adds a new body at (20,20) location, but I do not why `isActionUp()` does not fire, when I release the finger.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more clear - because you return 'false' to isActionDown - you don't then receive the isActionUp (you've made it clear you're not interested in the TouchEvent)

Basically...

Answer (score 1):

because you return false so whatever action was perform that do not action it.

you need to return true at last

```
return true;
```